# How to include tsconfig.json in prod build?

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, jhipster

In `tsconfig.json` I included `"resolveJsonModule": true`.

Locally, when I start the app with `npm run webpack:dev` everything goes smoothly.

However, while executing `npm run webpack:prod` it fails with: `but '--resolveJsonModule' is not used.`

So I guess the prod build doesn't take into account `tsconfig` file.

I believe the issue may lay somewhere in `webpack.js` files but I cannot find a specific place or variable.

Here are the aliases for run builds:

```
"webpack:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal",
"webpack:dev-verbose": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --profile --progress --env.stats=normal",
"webpack:build:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --env.stats=minimal",
"webpack:build": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:build:main",
"webpack:prod:main": "npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile",
"webpack:prod": "npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www",
"webpack:test": "npm run test",
"webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
```

Comment: In your tsconfig.json, do you also have allowSyntheticDefaultImports set to true? You’ll need that as well as resolveJsonModule.

Comment: I guess I don't have to set it. I'm able to import the json and work on the data from it just with the settings I posted. The issue here is the prod build that fails. But thanks for the suggestion anyways :)

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using Angular 8

Comment: did you eject your angular project why dont you use angular cli?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, project is generated by jHipster

Comment: @Xesenix JHipster projects do not use angular-cli for builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prod build uses `tsconfig-aot.json` as you can see in `webpack/webpack.prod.js`, make sure you add `"resolveJsonModule": true` to this file as well.